# echo bash variable in node spawn command

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, jenkins, spawn

Help me extrapolate bash variable value!

I've been googling around for some solutions, and thus far have not found an example of what I'm looking to do.

I've got a Jenkins job which is running a docker image containing a node runtime. During the creation of the docker image, some env vars were supplied (using `export`), which I would like to capture by spawning a child_process and using bash to extract the literal value the variable is pointing to.

For example, `const child = child_process.spawn('echo', ['$var']);`

I've tried every variation of quotes and escaping I can think of and I am not sure how to reference a bash variable from this command, invoked from inside a node script's spawned child process.

Please let me know if any of this is not clear. I have a preferred end solution, but it is blocked for now so I am trying to pursue this while we wait for the other solution to become available.

UPDATE FOR CLARITY - The env variable is stored in bash. You could normally access this by using `echo $var`. I am inside a bash shell running a node script, and I want to extrapolate the value to use in the node script by spawning a child process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In node you can access environment variables on global [`process`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) object:

```
process.env.MY_ENV_VAR
```

In your case:

```
const child = child_process.spawn('echo', [process.env.var]);
```

Comment: The variable is stored in bash, not node.

Comment: ah, I see what you are saying. If they are stored in .bash_profile, but they are not.

Answer (score 2):

### Use `printenv` instead of `echo`.

I had the same issue as you and the accepted answer here doesn't help. Not sure why it's accepted.

Try using `printenv` instead of `echo` to display the ENV value, like this:

```
const child = child_process.spawn( 'printenv', [ 'var' ] );
```

Comment: tbh this is a couple years old and so far out of context for me! I'll try to verify your answer

Comment: All good. Just wanted to add the solution that worked for me to help others that land here.